# fwrite not writing entire buffer

Tags: c, arrays, file, io, buffer

I am currently making a small test program for simple file checking. The program writes two small matrices(A and B) to files, closes and reopens them, reads in the matrices from the files, multiplies them and writes the resulting matrix(C) to a new file. It then closes and reopens this file containing the answer and prints it out for me to check if the IO operation proceeded correctly.

My problem is that the result matrix reads differently than expected.

I consider myself a beginner in C and of file input/output operations and this is the code that is causing me trouble. I am using WinXP, Codeblocks and Mingw.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define bufferA(i,k) (bufferA[i*cols+k])
#define bufferB(k,j) (bufferB[k*cols+j])
#define bufferC(i,j) (bufferC[i*cols+j])

void printMatrix(int *nMatrixToPrint, int nNumberOfElements, int nDimension) {
// This function prints out the element of an Array. This array represents a matrix in memory.

int nIndex;
printf("\n");

for (nIndex = 0; nIndex < nNumberOfElements; nIndex++) {
    if (nIndex % nDimension == 0)
        printf("\n");
    printf("%d,",nMatrixToPrint[nIndex]);
    }

return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int nElements = 16, nDim = 4;
int A[4][4] = {{1,2,3,1},{2,2,1,2},{4,2,3,1},{5,1,1,3}};
int B[4][4] = {{3,2,1,4},{2,2,3,3},{4,1,3,2},{2,2,5,1}};

// Create files of A and B, delete old ones if present
FILE *fpA = fopen("A.dat", "w+");
FILE *fpB = fopen("B.dat", "w+");

// Write data to them
fwrite((int*)A, sizeof(*A), nElements, fpA);
fwrite((int*)B, sizeof(*B), nElements, fpB);

// and close them
fclose(fpA);
fclose(fpB);

// Reopen files
fpA = fopen("A.dat", "r");
fpB = fopen("B.dat", "r");

// Allocate memory
int *bufferA = (int*)malloc(nElements * sizeof(*bufferA));
int *bufferB = (int*)malloc(nElements * sizeof(*bufferB));
int *bufferC = (int*)calloc(nElements, sizeof(*bufferC));

// Read files
fread(bufferA, sizeof(int), nElements, fpA);
fread(bufferB, sizeof(int), nElements, fpB);

printf("\nA");
printMatrix(bufferA, nElements, nDim);
printf("\n\nB");
printMatrix(bufferB, nElements, nDim);

// Matrix multiplication
// Calculate and write to C
int i,j,k = 0; // Loop indices
int n = nDim,l = nDim, m = nDim, cols = nDim;

// multiply
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {           // Columns
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {       // Rows
        //C(i,j) = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < l; k++) {
            bufferC(i,j) += bufferA(i,k) * bufferB(k,j);
        }
    }
}
printf("\n\nC_buffer");
printMatrix(bufferC, nElements, nDim);

// Create C and write to it
FILE* Cfile = fopen("C.dat", "w");
fwrite(bufferC, sizeof(*bufferC), nElements, Cfile);

// Close files
fclose(fpA);
fclose(fpB);
fclose(Cfile);

// reopen C for reading
Cfile = fopen("C.dat", "r");

// Obtain file size
fseek(Cfile , 0 , SEEK_END);
long lSize = ftell(Cfile);
rewind(Cfile);
printf("\nC file length is: %ld", lSize);

// read data into bufferA
fread(bufferA, sizeof(int), lSize, Cfile);
fclose(Cfile);

printf("\n\nC_file");
printMatrix(bufferA, nElements, nDim);

// Free allocated memory and remove dangling pointers
free(bufferA); bufferA = NULL;
free(bufferB); bufferB = NULL;
free(bufferC); bufferC = NULL;

exit(0);
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

A

1,2,3,1,
2,2,1,2,
4,2,3,1,
5,1,1,3,

B

3,2,1,4,
2,2,3,3,
4,1,3,2,
2,2,5,1,

C_buffer

21,11,21,17,
18,13,21,18,
30,17,24,29,
27,19,26,28,
C file length is: 64

C_file

21,11,21,17,
18,13,21,18,
30,17,24,29,
27,19,1,3,

As you can see, the last two elements in C_file are wrong, instead the output shows the last two elements in A as I was writing the file contents into bufferA. A switch to bufferB would swap the last two characters with the last elements in B which is still erroneous. A filecopy into another project would yield the last two integers as whatever was in ram at that malloc address.

My question is as follows: Why does not fwrite write the proper data into the file. Why does it manage the first 14 elements but not the last two? And how does this differ from my previous correct uses of fwrite and fread when I wrote and retrieved the elements of A and B?

Comment: Your call to fread isn't quite right; you'll attempt to read 64 values rather than 16 because the file is 64 bytes long. You probably want to switch the relevant parameter to lSize / sizeof(int). That shouldn't cause the problem though — have you tried logging the return result of fread? It should tell you the number of 'items' (ints in this case, since you specified sizeof(int)) read.

Comment: Thank you Tommy. I fixed the fread call and logged its return size_T which turned out to be 14, which is strange since the file on disk is 64 bytes which is 16 32-bit integers.

Comment: Sorry bro, your code works fine on my Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing binary data, and therefore you have to open the file in binary mode, the default is text mode. This makes a difference on windows, but not on *nix, which explains why it works for the other people here.

for all your [fopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) calls, include the letter 'b' in the mode argument, e.g. replace "w+" with "w+b" , replace "r" with "rb" and so on.

Comment: That was the indeed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I've experienced this before but now I'm having the same problem event with "rb" option.I told fwrite to write 239616 integers but it wrote only 3072, sometimes only 1024, sometimes 2048, it changes.  What can the problem be?

Comment: Oh I found when the buffer pointer is wrong, this can happen. I should have given fwrite(&buff[0], sizeof(int), count, fp); but I have given fwrite(&buff, sizeof(int),count,fp); by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your program runs just fine on my Mac.

The results would look better if printMatrix() output a final newline. Perhaps the unterminated line is causing some sort of confusion on your system?